# How to hide an element before the page loads or preload the scripts and the css

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, hoverintent

I’m using jQuery Mega Drop Down Menu Plugin by design chemical if you take a look at their example [here](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/examples/), you’ll see that when reloading the page, the drop down is properly displayed only when you hover over it. Below it, another example, when reloading the page it has a slight half a second delay so all of the ul tags below are displayed.

I’m using the menu on [this page](http://www.keystone.ultimatezencart.com/keystone/index.php?main_page=index) using bootstrap. I have tried fixing that delay by

1. giving the menu a display: none embedded in the html
2. giving the menu a display: none  as a style embedded in side the head tag before any other styles are loaded
3. attempting to preload the megamenu stylesheet and the javascript

The menu uses hoverIntent but like jQuery and Boostrap, I load it using CDN with a fallback.

Does anybody have any suggestions to avoid the slight delay or hiding the display of the menu before the page loads?

Thanks

Comment: doesn't `.sub-container{display:none !important;}` work? That's said, firstly you should fix errors as shown in console

Comment: no, that didn't work.